# LARAVEL8 Attempt to read property "POST" Invalid in "Clients Controller"

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create page where to add clients from. When I click submit it gives me this weird error about the POST being invalid and the error shows me the line in the controller where I first do the $request ->
I have no idea what I'm supposed to do. When I did the same thing for the users it worked just fine probably because I had most of the data and models already done from laravel breeze.

```
//Controller
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Clients;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateClientsRequest;

class ClientsController extends Controller
{
    public function showClients(){
        $clients= Clients::all()->sortby('cname');
        return view('admin.clients')->with('clients', $clients);
    }
    public function newClients(){
        return view('admin.clients-new');
    }
    public function createClients(Request $request){
        $clients = new Clients;
        $clients->cname->$request->cname;     // <------(this is where I get the error) ------>
        $clients->iban1->$request->iban1;
        $clients->iban2->$request->iban2;
        $clients->adresa->$request->adresa;
        $clients->punctdelucru->$request->punctdelucru;
        $clients->tara->$request->tara;
        $clients->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wrong syntax.

You need to assign the `$request` values to the new Client.
Instead of

```
$clients->cname->$request->cname;
```

you need to assign the value this way:

```
$clients->cname = $request->cname;
```

So your function `createClients` in your Controller should look like this:

```
public function createClients(Request $request){
        $clients = new Clients;
        $clients->cname = $request->cname;
        $clients->iban1 = $request->iban1;
        $clients->iban2 = $request->iban2;
        $clients->adresa = $request->adresa;
        $clients->punctdelucru = $request->punctdelucru;
        $clients->tara = $request->tara;
        $clients->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

But I would recommend you to do a validation of the entered values of the request, because you cannot trust the values entered by the user. Have a look at the docs how to implement validations:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation

Comment: Hello, these will not be entered by users, only by admins so I will trust the values.

Comment: Yes, but as far as I know, it always recommended to validate inputs - even when you're not expecting invalid or dangerous values.

Answer (score 0):

Verifica ce trimiti pe request, verifica daca ai coloanele alea in baza de date,
fa un **dd($request);** si zimi ce coloane ai in baza de date

Comment: Salut, coloanele din baza de date sunt identice, toate au valori de string, dd$request unde ar trb sa-l fac?

Comment: dd($request) il pui chiar in interior la functia createClients() ca sa faci debug si foloseste formatu asta : `$clients->cname = $request->cname;` nu formatu `$clients->cname-> $request->cname;` inlocuieste codu cu ce ti-a dat baiatu mai sus